# yup.js check array when condition

Tags: javascript, validation, testing, yup

I have an object with a flag as boolean and another item as array of objects.

I would like to check the array of objects only if the flag is true.

So:

```
{
  shouldCheck: false
}
```

this should pass

```
{
  shouldCheck: true
}
```

this should break

```
{
  shouldCheck: true,
  rules: []
}
```

this should break

```
{
  shouldCheck: true,
  rules: [1]
}
```

this should break

```
{
  shouldCheck: true,
  rules: [{other: 'xx'}]
}
```

this should break

```
{
  shouldCheck: true,
  rules: [right: 'one']
}
```

this should pass

yup schema:

```
const delaySchema = yup.object().shape({
  shouldCheck: yup.boolean(),
  rules: yup.mixed()
    .when(['shouldCheck'], {
      is: (sck) => {
        return sck;
      },
    then: yup.array().of(yup.object().shape({
      right: yup.string().required(),
    })),
    otherwise: yup.mixed().nullable()
  }),
});
```

now the problem here is that it ignores the internal value and dont check them.

Answer (score 7):

try to use yup.**array()** before condition

```
const delaySchema = yup.object().shape({
  shouldCheck: yup.boolean(),
  rules: yup.array()
    .when(['shouldCheck'], {
      is: (sck) => {
        return sck;
      },
    then: yup.array().of(yup.object().shape({
      right: yup.string().required(),
    })),
    otherwise: yup.mixed().nullable()
  }),
});
```